# Deleting text from text box

Tags: .net, vb.net, textbox

I am trying to delete text from my text box once it gets to a certain amount of characters. I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub MainTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MainTextBox.TextChanged

    If MainTextBox.Text.Length >= 50 Then
        MainTextBox.Text.Remove(1, 10)
    End If

End Sub
```

When I execute the code, it does not give me any error messages or anything the code runs perfectly, but it does not delete the text like I want it to. Any help?

Comment: Note that all string methods are zero-based, so the first character is at index 0. `String.Remove(1,10)` returns a new string with the remaining characters, removed are char2-char12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable, that means you cannot modify them without creating a new string.

```
MainTextBox.Text = MainTextBox.Text.Remove(1, 10)
```

However, your code makes little sense. Do you want   to  shorten the text to a certain amount of characters?

```
If MainTextBox.Text.Length >= 50 Then
    MainTextBox.Text = MainTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 50))    
End If
```

Comment: Look at that! haha thank you! I can accept an answer in 11 minutes.